# How to shift the columns of image in python

Tags: python

I want to straight the diagnol lines of image by using the trick in which we generate the black image whose size is greater than the original image then we shift columns of original image into black image in such a way that we shift the first column of image on one pixel then second column on 2 pixels ,3rd column on 3 pixels and so on and But problem is that I enable to do this in python .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsp3X.png)

Pl! help me How can I do this.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program which creates a new image with each column offset by 1 more pixel than the last. I used the PIL module to do this. Just change `"image.png"` in line 3 to the name of your image.

[Here is the output I got using your image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwWLq.png)

Here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("image.png")

new_height = sum(img.size)
new_img = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(img.size[0], new_height))

y_offset = 0
for column in range(img.size[0]):
    for pix in range(img.size[1]):
        col = img.getpixel((column, pix))
        new_img.putpixel((column, pix + y_offset), col)

    y_offset += 1

new_img.save("new_img.png")
```

Comment: If this answers your question please make sure to mark it as the correct answer. Also, next time please try to find out the answer to the question yourself before asking on stack overflow. Also, a bit more context and improved grammar would be preferred. ;)